# Why is my innerList is not adding in the answers?

Tags: java, list, recursion, combinations, recursive-backtracking

This question is of combination sum. I tried it through recursion and backtracking but my output is becoming an empty list of lists every time.

```
public class CombinationSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] candidates = {2,3,6,7};
        System.out.println(combinationSum(candidates,8));
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> currComb = new ArrayList<>();
        getResult(candidates,target,currComb,0,0,ans);
        return ans;
    }

    public static void getResult(int[] candidates,int target, List<Integer> currComb, int currSum, int currIndex,List<List<Integer>> ans) {
        if (currSum > target) {
            return;
        }
        if (currSum == target) {
            ans.add(currComb);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length ; i++) {
            currComb.add(candidates[i]);
            currSum += candidates[i];
            getResult(candidates, target, currComb, currSum, i, ans);
            currComb.remove(currComb.size() -1);
            currSum -= candidates[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing this does wrong?

Comment: Is this C# or Java?  You didn't tag it.

Comment: @TimRoberts  `System.out.println` seems like java

Comment: You are always operating on the very same inner list and never create a new one. Thus all your `currComb.add()` and `currComb.remove()` is in fact operating on the very same list.

Comment: Remember that `ans.add(currComb)` does not make a COPY of the list.  You only allocate two lists in this entire program.  The first list (`ans`) is going to end up containing many references to the other list (`currComb`).  Every time you change `currComb`, you change all the lists in `ans`.

Comment: What is "combination sum" *supposed* to do?

Comment: In addition to what @TimRoberts said, `getResult` takes a parameter `currIndex` which it never uses. It should be the starting offset of the `for` loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that are wrong with this code of yours.

```
ans.add(currComb);
```

This would always give you the wrong result even if your code was right. List is a reference type in Java so you should always add a new instance of list in your answer.
For example

```
ans.add(new ArrayList(currComb));
```

You are passing in currIndex but you are not using it. You probably need to call your recursive function twice to simulate whether or not you are adding it to your list.

I solved this question last night on LeetCode. This was my code and it worked for me.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList();
        if(nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
            return res;
        }
        dfs(res, nums, 0,target, new ArrayList());
        return res;
    }
    public void dfs(List<List<Integer>> res, int[] nums, int i, int target, List<Integer> temp) {
        if(target == 0) {
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
            return;
        }
        if(target < 0 || i >= nums.length) {
            return;
        }
        
        temp.add(nums[i]);
        dfs(res, nums, i, target - nums[i], temp);
        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
        dfs(res, nums, i+1, target, temp);
    }
}
```